# How to loop bottom-top a hierarchy (for automatic layout manager)?

Tags: layout, hierarchy, layout-manager

I have a hierarchy of UIObjects that has automatic layout managers and in order to calculate their preferred size I need to loop all the hierarchy from the most bottom item to the root item.

They currently are stored like this:

root.children[{children: [{...}, {...}, {...}]}, {...}, {...}]

{...} = UIObject

(language=javascript)

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you want to calculate result size of parent container?

Comment: so you task is to solve expression TotalWidth = [[ UIObject1.width +  UIObject2.width +  UIObject3.width] +  UIObject4.width + UIObject5.width]... where [el1 + el2] means elements(el1, el2) has the same parent